# Expansion of nonlinear functions with damping properties in exponential series

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, approximation

I am working on solving nonlinear differential equations and found such a solution with exponential properties.
$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{d}{dx}(sech(x)^2)$

The solution of which is:

$x(t) = \sinh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{LambertW\left(e^{c_1-4 t}\right)}\right)$

where $c_1$ - arbitrary constant.

Let's assume that $c_1 = 20$.

```
Plot[{ArcSinh[Sqrt[ProductLog[Exp[20 - 4 t]]]]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

**If we assume that this signal contains an exponential component, a nonlinear wave component that distorts this signal, then the question arises: is it possible to expand the solution of the differential equation in a series of exponentials that would approximate the solution to the equation well?**

$ProbablyQuasiSolution = e^{-p_1 \cdot t} + e^{-p_2 \cdot t} ... e^{-p_n \cdot t}$

Some of the components that, in my opinion, are present in the solution, I reflected in the second plot.

```
Plot[{ArcSinh[Sqrt[ProductLog[Exp[20 - 4 t]]]], 2.12 Exp[-t], 
  ArcSinh[Sqrt[ProductLog[Exp[20 - 4 t]]]] - 2.12 Exp[-t], 
  6.4 (Exp[-1/2 t] - Exp[-1 t])}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: This does not seem to be a question on Mathematica, but a question for a math forum or a forum specific to your field of work.

Comment: I was hoping that the `Series` command, which I don't know well, would help me. Can she help me?

Comment: I had a look at `Series` and `NonlinearModelFit`. They don't give good approximations. What are you trying to do? An interpolated version of the function would be the simplest way of approximating it.

Comment: I need to get an approximation of the solution of a non-linear differential equation in order to be able to do the Laplace transform of this.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that it will be not easy to do with simple exponents, since they are bent downwards, while your curve  - upwards. However, you can do this with exponents of even powers of t. If that is Ok with you try this:

```
lst = Table[{t, ArcSinh[Sqrt[ProductLog[Exp[20 - 4 t]]]]}, {t, 0, 10, 
    0.5}];
```

which makes a list out of your function. Then

```
Manipulate[
 model = a*Exp[-(t/T1)^2] + b*Exp[-(t/T2)^4];
 ff = FindFit[lst, model, {a, b}, t];
 Show[{
   ListPlot[lst],
   Plot[model /. ff, {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red]
   }], {{T1, 2.29}, 0.1, 4, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{T2, 5.08}, 1, 
  8, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

yielding the following fitting

[image]

Of course, you may play with parameters as well as try to add more terms with other powers.

Have fun!